# ADODB find on a recordset

Tags: vba, excel, adodb, recordset

In Excel 2010, I'm writing a vb application that loads a big text file into a recordset.
The text file is a log file, separated with space and without any first line for the column headers.
I'm able to load the file into a recordset by using an appropriate schema.ini file.
The file logs users logins into a database.

The user account is in the 10th column of the text file (so 9th one in the recordset).
I would like to know what is the last login date for a given user.

Here is the code I use, giving me 3001 error. Where I'm trying to get the last record for user account named psymonds.

```
' LOAD login_history.txt file to a recordset called rs
strPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
strcon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strPath & ";Extended Properties=""text;HDR=No;FMT=Delimited"";"
cn.Open strcon
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM login_history.txt;"

Set rs = CreateObject("adodb.recordset")
rs.CursorType = adOpenKeyset
rs.LockType = adLockOptimistic
rs.Open strSQL, cn


rs.MoveFirst
rs.Find "rs.Fields(9) = '" & "psymonds" & "'", , 1, 2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have no headers, the recordset fields will be named F1, F2 and so on, so you can use:

```
rs.Find "[F10] = 'psymonds'", , 1, 2
```

Comment: Was about to add a comment, but I didn't know about the [F#colnum#] syntax.  Nice!